# DNS issues with Cloudflare & Netlify

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting

I have a domain name `example.com` that I've had for years for my web design business. The registrar is GoDaddy, I have my DNS hosted at Cloudflare and I'm wanting to create a new site with Netlify. I have clients who point their domains to my server at `ns1.example.com` and `ns2.example.com`. I'm now trying to keep my clients sites online but also move my `example.com` main site to Netlify.

What DNS records do I need to add to Cloudflare so I won't take down my clients sites who are pointing to my nameservers?

Answer (score 0):

This depends if you're intending to move the DNS hosting from Cloudflare to Netlify or not.

If you're sticking with Cloudflare, [you can just follow this guide](https://docs.netlify.com/domains-https/custom-domains/configure-external-dns/#configure-a-subdomain), and it won't affect your name servers as the records will still be in place for the name servers.

If you're moving the DNS over to Netlify, you'll need to create records for the name servers so that anybody resolving you clients DNS records can find them.

This is all dependent on you just moving your site to Netlify, and keeping the name servers as they are. I'm fairly certain that you can't move your name servers over to Netlify.

If you can post a redacted version of your Cloudflare DNS configuration in an edit I can have a closer look.